# Local settings in Windows Phone 8.1 app are not stored

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, winrt-xaml

I have created many apps for Windows Phone 7 and 8. To store settings I was using these methods:

```
IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings["key"] = value;
IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Save();
```

Everything worked perfectly, my settings were stored. `Save()` method did the job.

But now I am creating an app for Windows Phone 8.1 (WinRT). I have followed [this guide](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh700361.aspx) to learn hot to save settings. Ane here is how it looks like now:

```
Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings.Values["key"] = value;
```

But when I close the app and run again, they're gone, my settings are not stored. So my question is: How to **save** settings in Windows Phone 8.1?

Comment: The line above should work (definitely works for me), so a couple of checks to make: 1. define "close the app and run again" - are you closing an emulator? Is Visual Studio delete-ing and re-installing the app you are deploying to a device? 2. Define "value" - what are you trying to store?

Comment: I'm not closing the emulator/device, just the app. The value is a short string, like "Nick", nothing fancy.

Comment: Have you tried the line above in a new blank project?

Comment: OK, it works now. I tried this using biding to TextBox. It worked in WP7/8 but not in 8.1. Here I had to use this method in standard way. Thanks for your help. ;)

Comment: No prpblem! Glad it works for you now!

Comment: @ŁukaszRejman please add your solution as an answer and accept it.  That'll get this question out of the unanswered area.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line really works:

```
 Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings.Values["key"] = value;
```

The problem is when you're trying to call it via binding in XAML as a property. Then you may have problem with it. Just avoid it, and call this method in code behind explicite.