# Saving a DateTime value to Local Settings [UWP]

Tags: c#, uwp

In my UWP app I'm trying to save a DateTime value to local settings with this code:

```
        localSettings.Values["date"] = myDate;
```

The problem is that when I try to retrieve the value I get a cast error. I'm using this code to retrieve the value:

```
    DateTime dateRecovered = (DateTime)localSettings.Values["date"];
```

Comment: What's in `myDate`?

Comment: What's the error? Have you even tried looking into it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Local settings in Windows Phone 8.1 app are not stored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30560722/local-settings-in-windows-phone-8-1-app-are-not-stored)

Comment: There are  similar questions in this paradigm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can refer to the official documentation [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br206576)

The supported type for date is `System.DateTimeOffset` , not `System.DateTime`. So, you can modify your code like this:

```
ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings.Values["date"] = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow;
```